# Elastic search Nest (.Net) Total and Documents don't match

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm having the following situation: the Total from the Valid Nest Response is equals 2 and the Documents count equal 0. I'm not sure how that is possible.

[image: quickwatch from debugger]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem was in my model. You see, my model was something like that:

```
public class Customer
    {        
        public string Id { get; set; }        

        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        
        public string PersonType { get; set; }
        
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
        
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And this Index had Documents missing some fields, like:

```
public class Customer
    {        
        public string Id { get; set; }        

        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public string PersonType { get; set; }
        
        public string Gender { get; set; }        
    }
```

The solution was adding the decorator PropertyName from Nest, to Map my model, like this:

```
public class Customer
    {
        [PropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("nickname")]
        public string Nickname { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("personType")]
        public string PersonType { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("gender")]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("maritalStatus")]
        public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("birthDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Now it works!